# How does Haskell function `tell` work

Tags: haskell

I'm learning `do expression` and `Monad` using *LEARN YOU A HASKELL FOR GREAT GOOD*. There's a `gcd` implementation using `tell` function makes me confused.

```
gcd :: Int -> Int -> Writer [String] Int
gcd a b
  | b == 0 = tell ["Finished with " ++ show a ] >>= (\_ -> return a)
  | otherwise = tell [show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b)] >>= (\_ -> gcd b (a `mod` b))

gcdResult = gcd 8 3

-- result: WriterT (Identity (1,["8 mod 3 = 2","3 mod 2 = 1","2 mod 1 = 0","Finished with 1"]))
```

But I am confused by the `tell` function. When using `>>= (\_ -> ...)` or `>>`, the result before will be ignored, so why does the result of `tell` can be passed to the final result? As my thought, the `tell` result may be ignored, and the final result will be `WriterT (Identity (1,[]))`.

Comment: Note that, for the `Monad` instance for `Writer`, you have `(>>) :: Monoid w => Writer w a -> Writer w b -> Writer w b`. You can see just the last type argument of the first function argument is "ignored" (the type `a`). A bit more explicitly (`~` is equality of types), the `m ~ (Writer w)`, so `(>>) :: Monoid w => (Writer w) a -> (Writer w) b -> (Writer w) b`.

Comment: It is a little above my level but I understood your comment after I read @Silvio 's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're confusing the result with the context. You are correct that, when applying `>>` or `>>= \_ ->`, the result of the left-hand-side is ignored. However, if the entire value was ignored, it would be completely pointless; the monadic context can be passed forward.

```
a >> b
```

This means "take the context from `a` and combine it with the context of `b`, keeping the result value of `b`". In the case of `Writer`, the monadic context is that there is some write-only data being passed about.

```
tell :: Monoid w => w -> Writer w ()
```

This is the (somewhat simplified) type of `tell`. It takes a value to write and returns a `Writer` instance whose result value is insignificant (`()`) but whose context is that there is a write-only value containing the `w` argument. When you apply `>>`, the result value is ignored (which is irrelevant because `tell` returns nothing of value through its result) but the *context* is kept.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It makes me totally understand it.